# Multiple Syncadapters in the same Application

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I need to have two separate syncs in my app. One is done every 12 hrs. Another is done every week. I want to have them both under the same "account", so each type of sync can be enabled/disabled separately.

Actually, the accounts are dummies - I don't need that functionality, so all my authenticator methods return null.

But I'm only able to get one syncadapter to show up for an account. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: Is the content being synced the same for both syncs, or different?

Comment: Is there an absolute need for two? Why not store the last time you synced for the weekly sync in a sqlite table? Have the sync adapter run every 12 hours and check when the last time you synced for the weekly sync and sync if need be. This eliminates the need for two SyncAdapters.